# ListPlot with PlotRange -> Automatic giving unexpected results in V.9

Tags: plotting, version-9

There seem to be a problem with `ListPlot` auto ranging in *Mathematica* 9.

Here's my code:

```
n = 10;
dn = 10;
data = Table[If[Divisible[i - n, dn], i, 1], {i, 1,  100}];
ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Automatic]
```

In version 8 it works as expected (y ranges from 0 to 100), but in version 9 it only shows y going from 0 to 2. Is there something wrong with my code? A bug in *Mathematica*?

Comment: I have `y` range from 0 to 100 in Wolfram Mathematica 9.0.1.

Comment: In v. 9.0.1, as the documentation for `PlotRange` indicates, "outlying points are dropped."

Comment: `PlotRange -> All` gives {0, 100} range

Comment: @m0nhawk Strange. I also use 9.0.1. Platform Windows 64. Which platform are you on?

Comment: `y: {0, 2}` under _Mathematica_ 9.0.1.0 Win7 x64.
`y: {0, 100}` under _Mathematica_ 8.0.0.0 Linux x86. Interestingly, there is no indication in the doc under `PlotRange` (in v9) that it has ben modified since v8.

Comment: @Max: **Platform:** Microsoft Windows (64-bit)

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point but "`Automatic`" and "outlying points" are not very precise statements so I would not expect any specific behaviour. So do not worry :) @IstvánZachar Ah, another one to the list of hidden updates. :/

Comment: @István Zachar I'm also on Mathematica 9.0.1.0 Win7 x64 (with the {0, 2} range), but m0nhawk sees {0, 100} on windows 64 bit in MMA 9. Maybe it's not Windows 7? In any case if that behavior is platform specific, then it's not correct.

Comment: @David The same is true for *Mathematica* 6 and 5.2: see corresponding legacy documentation pages: [v6](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v6/ref/PlotRange.html#11957), [v.5.2](http://reference.wolfram.com/legacy/v5_2/functions/PlotRange).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see all the points, including outliers, use `PlotRange->All` 
instead of `PlotRange->Automatic`.

```
n = 10; dn = 10; data = Table[If[Divisible[i - n, dn], i, 1], {i, 1,  100}];
{ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> Automatic], ListPlot[data, PlotRange -> All]}
```

[image]